# How to set coder for JdbcIO in Apache Beam without using deprecated withCoder method?

Tags: java, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm currently working with Apache Beam's JdbcIO, and I need to set a coder for the input data. However, the `withCoder` method is marked as deprecated, and I want to avoid using deprecated methods. Here's a snippet of my code:

```java
.apply("Inserting", JdbcIO.<PubsubMessage, InboundData>readAll()
        .withDataSourceProviderFn(DataSourceProvider.of(dbConfig))
        .withQuery("SELECT column1, column2, column3, array_agg(column4) as aggregated_column " +
                "FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id " +
                "WHERE table1.condition1 = ? and table1.condition2 = ? GROUP BY column1, column2, column3")
        .withParameterSetter((element, preparedStatement) -> {
            Map<String, String> attributeMap = Objects.requireNonNull(element.getAttributeMap());
            preparedStatement.setString(1, attributeMap.get("condition1"));
            preparedStatement.setString(2, attributeMap.get("condition2"));
        })
        .withRowMapper(resultSet -> {
            // Mapping logic here
        }).withOutputParallelization(false)
).setCoder(SerializableCoder.of(InboundData.class))
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to infer a coder for JdbcIO.readAll() transform. Provide a coder via withCoder, or ensure that one can be inferred from the provided RowMapper.
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.Preconditions.checkStateNotNull(Preconditions.java:471)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$ReadAll.expand(JdbcIO.java:1094)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$ReadAll.expand(JdbcIO.java:941)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:548)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:499)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:373)
        at mrch.prcmgmt.backend.price.MassiveLoadCommand.run(MassiveLoadCommand.java:73)
        at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:1939)
        at picocli.CommandLine.access$1300(CommandLine.java:145)
...
```

So my question is: As withCoder is deprecated, what is the recommended way to set the coder for JdbcIO?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Beam tries to infer the coder based on the defined class of the RowMapper. But it cannot infer that from the lambda expression.

So changing your `withRowMapper` implementation to

```
.withRowMapper(new JdbcIO.RowMapper<OutputType>() {

                        public Output mapRow(ResultSet resultSet)  {

                            // logic here

                        }
                    })
```

Should fix the issue.